# What does 'marks' refer to in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> “What were you doing out of your dormitory at four in the morning?” said Bill, surveying his mother with amazement.
>
> Mrs. Weasley grinned, her eyes twinkling.
>
> “Your father and I had been for a nighttime stroll,” she said. “He got
>   caught by Apollyon Pringle - he was the caretaker in those days - your
>   father's still got the **marks**.”

I'm not sure what 'marks' refers to. Is it *the marks for each house*, *the marks on his father's body* or something else?

From Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the wound scar after Apollyon Pringle punished Arthur.

Comment: Quite appropriate, given Apollyon was a Devil in "Pilgrim's Progress".